# iterative functions in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I’m trying to create multiple new score columns based on other columns. I’d like to use a function to minimize copy pasting large blocks of code.

I’m trying to do something like:

```
Myfunction <- function(column){

 Column_df <- old_df %>%

  mutate(column.score = if_else(column = 1, “yes”, “no”)

   )

 }

Score_df <- Myfunction(c(math, reading, science)))
```

But I’m getting an error saying object math is not found

Comment: This cannot work for several reasons. Please provide sample data, see `?dput()`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an example data frame as below

```r
df <- purrr::map_dfc(c('math', 'reading', 'science', 'history'),
                     ~ rlang::list2(!!.x := sample(1:3, 10, TRUE)))
df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>     math reading science history
#>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#>  1     2       1       3       1
#>  2     3       2       3       1
#>  3     2       2       2       2
#>  4     2       3       1       2
#>  5     3       3       1       2
#>  6     1       2       3       2
#>  7     3       3       2       1
#>  8     3       3       3       2
#>  9     1       2       2       1
#> 10     2       2       2       3
```

You can create new "score" columns with a function by passing your `columns` argument to `across` inside `{{ }}`, and using the `.name` option to add ".score" to the name.

If you want only the "score" columns in the output, rather than to add them to existing columns, use `transmute` instead of `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

Myfunction <- function(df, columns){
  df %>% 
    mutate(across({{ columns }}, ~ if_else(. == 1, 'yes', 'no'),
                  .names = '{.col}.score'))
}

df %>% 
  Myfunction(c(math, reading, science))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 7
#>     math reading science history math.score reading.score science.score
#>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>      <chr>         <chr>        
#>  1     2       1       3       1 no         yes           no           
#>  2     3       2       3       1 no         no            no           
#>  3     2       2       2       2 no         no            no           
#>  4     2       3       1       2 no         no            yes          
#>  5     3       3       1       2 no         no            yes          
#>  6     1       2       3       2 yes        no            no           
#>  7     3       3       2       1 no         no            no           
#>  8     3       3       3       2 no         no            no           
#>  9     1       2       2       1 yes        no            no           
#> 10     2       2       2       3 no         no            no
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: im getting "No applicable useMethod for function"?

Comment: If the error you got was actually "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"", then one possible explanation is that you're running the code without first either (a) defining a data frame called `df` or (b) changing `df` in the code to the name of your existing data frame. I don't think the error you quoted is a real R error message.